# When the GA4 is automatically created, are all accesses from the past carried over or not?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

When automatically creating a GA4 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH0I9.png), are all accesses from the past (source resource) transferred or not?

For example:
There is a UA resource that I only have read access to. If I automatically create a GA4 resource for it, will I have the same level of access to the new GA4 resource?

There's nothing in here about accesses:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12938611?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are `opting in` for ***automatically*** creating a GA4 property:

- Your `property-level` users will be copied over and have the same level of access as that of the UA property. (Only users who have access to the UA property will be copied over and will retain access to the new GA4 property)
- If someone only has a `view level` access, they won't have any access to the new GA4 property

[Official Docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12938611?hl=en#howitworks&zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Ccopy-ua-property-level-users)

> Your new Google Analytics 4 property will have the same Universal
> Analytics ***property-level users*** with equivalent permissions.
> ***View-level users won't be copied***.